# Depth only attachment in OpenGL ES

Tags: opengl-es, shadow

I previously had depth only attachment in opengles and it gave error that framebuffer has incomplete attachment. When I added color attachment it worked. So it seems like depth only attachment is not supported in es. But with this approach there will be memory wastage. Is there any workaround for this when implementing shadow mapping?

Comment: Not having a color attachment should be completely fine. What status did you get? Was it `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT`? If that's the case, I suspect that there's something else going on, like having an invalid color attachment that you might have missed to detach.

Comment: @RetoKoradi yes, it was GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT, but that was due to missing color attachment. when i added color attachment, all the errors gone.